# Android Async XML Parsing

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, android-asynctask

I was trying to parse XML from a url and show it on a listview. But, listview is showing 
like this

http://postimg.org/image/ucbdjpwj5/

[I can't post any image directly here, because my reputation is under 10 ]

Here are my code

**MainActivity**

```
getRssDataTask ts = new getRssDataTask();
    ts.execute("http://www.xyzapp.com/feed");
}


private class getRssDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<NewsItem>>{

    @Override
    protected List<NewsItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
                // Create RSS reader
                RSSReader rssReader = new RSSReader(params[0]);

                // Parse RSS, get items
                return rssReader.getItems();

        } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("App", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<NewsItem> result) {

        ListView Items = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // Create a list adapter
        ArrayAdapter<NewsItem> rs = new ArrayAdapter<NewsItem>(local,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
        // Set list adapter for the ListView
        Items.setAdapter(rs);
```

**RssHandler**

```
public class RssHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private List<NewsItem> rssItem;

    private NewsItem currentItem;

    private boolean parsingTitle;

    private boolean parsingDes;

    public RssHandler() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        rssItem = new ArrayList<NewsItem>();
    }

    public List<NewsItem> getItems() {
        return rssItem;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if ("item".equals(qName)) {
            currentItem = new NewsItem();
        } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
            parsingTitle = true;
        } else if ("content:encoded".equals(qName)) {
            parsingDes = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if ("item".equals(qName)) {
            rssItem.add(currentItem);
            currentItem = null;
        } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
            parsingTitle = false;
        } else if ("content:encoded".equals(qName)) {
            parsingDes = false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (parsingTitle) {
            if (currentItem != null)
                currentItem.setTitle(new String(ch, start, length));
        } else if (parsingDes) {
            if (currentItem != null) {
                currentItem.setDes(new String(ch, start, length));
                parsingDes = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RssReader**

```
public class RSSReader {

    private String RssUrl;
    public RSSReader(String RssUrl) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.RssUrl = RssUrl;
    }

    public List<NewsItem> getItems() throws Exception{

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        RssHandler handler = new RssHandler();

        saxParser.parse(RssUrl, handler);

        return handler.getItems();

    }
}
```

I was unable to figure out the problem. My question is what wrong I am doing ?

Comment: you need to override `toString()` in `NewsItem`

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following method in NewsItem:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  // return a String value representing this object
  // Assuming two class String properties called title and description
  return title + ": " + description;
}
```

Comment: I have two String Title and Description. How can I return two string at a same time ?

Comment: edited answer. Assuming you have two String properties in your class. It's up to you how you create a formatted String value to return. I've used a ':' character to separate the 2 strings